# python twilio flask: index out of range

Tags: python, flask, sms, twilio, ngrok

I'm setting up a twillo SMS bot and want to split the incoming response for flask in to a list and checking and check if the response has an `add` , `list`, `remove`

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])


#define method to split the input


def sms_ahoy_reply():



    """Respond to incoming messages with a friendly SMS."""
    # Start our response
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    country = request.values.get('FromCountry')
    toDoList = []
    splitext = request.args.get('body','').split()
    msgSplit = list(splitext)
    if msgSplit[0] == 'add':
        toDoList.append(msgSplit[1:])
    elif msgSplit[0] == 'list':
        resp.message(msgSplit[1:])
    elif msgSplit[0] == 'remove':
        deL = msgSplit[1]
        if deL!=0:
            del msgSplit[deL-1]
        else:
            del msgSplit[deL]


    # Add a message
    resp.message("Hi! It looks like your phone number was born in %s" %country)


    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you post your GET/POST request here? Without it, I don't think anyone can figure out the problem. I think `request.args.get('body','')` is not present.

Comment: Sidebar, but you can easily and programmatically manage `ngrok` from Python application using `pyngrok`. Flask example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask).

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

You should change `splitext = request.args.get('body','').split()` to `splitext = request.values.get('body','').split()`.

`request.args` is the key/value pairs in the URL query string (ie. http://website.com/index?arg1=hello&arg2=world). Use for URL Query parameter, to fetch parameters from a URL with a GET request

`request.values` is the combined `args` and `form`.
More info is [here in the Flask docs.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request)